# Using science paper's method in commercial product

Tags: copyright, contract-law, commerce, paperwork, building-code

Is it possible to use the method (method or algorithm, model, etc.) described in an open scientific publication (license is arbitrary) in a commercial product in closed source code? That is, the essence of the question is as follows: here is a publication, it has an author and an owner of exclusive rights (like any work). It is prohibited to take and copy the TEXT of the publication without the author's permission in accordance with copyright (unless the author has attached the appropriate license). If the TEXT of the publication contains CODE implementing the method, algorithm, etc. described in the publication, then it is also prohibited to use it without permission. But is it possible, for example, to create a commercial product based on the method described in the article, if the company implements the entire implementation of the method in the form of code independently? At the same time, no permission is required from the author.

This is a really subtle point that is not explicitly described anywhere, please help me deal with this issue.

Comment: Is the method in the paper patented?

Comment: @Trish No, it lsn't patented

Answer (score 3):

The relevant law here is patent law, and the comment makes clear that the idea is not protected by a patent.

This is not a "subtle point". The laws allow everything that's not forbidden.

Comment: Tell me, please, what can I refer to (and in what way) if I use the method/method/algorithm described in the article (but not patented)?

Comment: You're imagining problems. Just refer to the paper.

Comment: thanks for feedback